# UILabel bounces as text is added

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Text is programmatically added to a UILabel. The text wraps and increases the height of the label as more text is added.

The problem is, when the text wraps at the end of a line, the entire label will jump up the height of 1 line and animate itself back down into it's proper position. The end result is fine, but how do you get rid of the strange jumping animation. Again, this happens each time the UILabel's height increases due to another line wrap.

**Sample code:**

```
var eventCount = 0;
func someEvent(sender:AnyObject){
    eventCount += 1;
    if(eventCount == 1){
        lbl.text = "this"
    }else if(eventCount == 2){
        lbl.text = "this is some" 
    }else if(eventCount == 3){
        lbl.text = "this is some sample text" 
    }else if(eventCount == 4){
        // this is where text wraps to line 2 
        // the label jumps up 20px or so and 
        //  animates back down to it's original position 
        lbl.text = "this is some sample text that causes the label to wrap" 
    }
}
```

**AutoLayout Constraints**

```
            0
            |
     0 - UILabel - 0
```

**Label Properties**

```
lines = 0
```

Comment: added sample code; thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Did you try `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` when you add text?

Comment: Yes, tried it before, after and both. Still get the same effect.

Comment: I couldn't duplicate this - can you give some more info? What version of Xcode? What's the view hierarchy? Are there any other non-default properties?

Comment: Could you add your constraint setup code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce the problem with following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
            self.someEvent(self)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func someEvent(sender:AnyObject){
        self.label.text! += " test"
    }
}
```

So, I believe your `someEvent()` is called within animation blocks.

`UIView.performWithoutAnimation` solves the problem.

```
var eventCount = 0;
func someEvent(sender:AnyObject){
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self.eventCount += 1;
        if(self.eventCount == 1){
            self.lbl.text = "this"
        }else if(self.eventCount == 2){
            self.lbl.text = "this is some"
        }else if(self.eventCount == 3){
            self.lbl.text = "this is some sample text"
        }else if(self.eventCount == 4){
            self.lbl.text = "this is some sample text that causes the label to wrap"
        }
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for taking the time to reproduce this. Strangely enough, the bug cleared itself up, so it may be an intermittent problem. It's now working fine on both my complex screen and simple test case. No animation blocks involved, but I'll give you the bounty if no other insight is offered into this bug. Thanks again!